# How to draw an octagon not regular?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I want to draw an octagon that has no 3 diagonal passing through the same point. For that, I want to draw an octagon that is not regular. Why does not compile correctly?

```
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 

\tkzDefPoint(5,0){A}

\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)

\tkzDefPoint({5*cos(75^{\circ})},{5*sin(75^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P1}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(110^{\circ})},{5\sin(110^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P2}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(140^{\circ)},{5*sin(140^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P3}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(190^{\circ)},{5*sin(190^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P4}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(200^{\circ)},{5*sin(200^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P5}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(240^{\circ)},{5*sin(240^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoinP{P6}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(290^{\circ)},{5*sin(290^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P7}

 \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(310^{\circ)},{5*sin(310^{\circ)}) \tkzGetPoint{P8}

\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red!50!Gold,ultra thick](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red!50!Gold,size=15](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove all the `^{\circ}`. Can't you just shift the vertices around a bit? Change the radius and angles slightly.

Comment: And after the `\tkzDefPoint(...)` a `{}` with the name of the point should follow.

Comment: You should also study the manual of `tkz-euclide` a bit more closely. Even if it is in a language you don't understand, there are a lot of examples. One working point definition would be `\tkzDefPoint({5*cos(75)},{5*sin(75)}){P1}`.

Comment: And don't close curly parenthesis with round ones, e.g. `{\circ)`

Comment: You need a document class line if you want to compile without errors using the LaTeX format.

Comment: Now it works, I did, after valuable suggestions. Although not master 100% the package syntax, I managed today to make lot of progress!!!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem of your code is that you're confusing typesetting syntax (`\circ`, `\sin`) with syntax for calculations. You also have some mismatched braces/parenthesis, as Sam Carter pointed out in a comment. A working definition of a point would be

```
\tkzDefPoint({5*cos(75)},{5*sin(75)}){P1}
```

The next problem is that the trigonometric functions in `fp`, that `tkz-euclide` uses, assumes radians, while you use degrees.

Complete example below. I used a loop to define the points.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O} 
\tkzDefPoint(5,0){A}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)

\foreach[count=\i] \ANG in {75,110,140,190,200,240,290,310} {
   \tkzDefPoint({5*cos(\ANG*pi/180)},{5*sin(\ANG*pi/180)}){P\i}
}

\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red!50!Gold,ultra thick](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)

\tkzDrawPoints[color=red!50!Gold,size=15](P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)
\tkzLabelPoints(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The trigonometric functions in `pgf` require degrees ! But `tkz-euclide` uses `fp` and the trigonometric functions of `fp` require radians.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Ah right, I wasn't thinking clearly. Will edit.